# src/Xerces.cpp:13:10: fatal error: dom/DOMAttr.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, xquery, ubuntu-18.04, pypi

I am tring to install PyExerces. But I got gcc compile error. Is this kind of thing normal in python in Ubuntu?

(I hardly found XQuery lib in Python which is XQilla, XQilla needs PyExerces, and "pip install PyXerces" gives following error. 
There is also Zorba for python Xquery lib. But it is an old outdated project whose required packages not available for Ubuntu 18 anymore. What is going on for python? :) It is very disappointing to not able to find XQuery lib for Python..)

```
erhan@erhan-VirtualBox:~$ sudo pip install PyXerces
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
WARNING: The directory '/home/erhan/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: The directory '/home/erhan/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting PyXerces
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bf/64/421bc05f5b679ba95cc9bde319ad824406fa5522bef3621ba9125edf16bf/PyXerces-0.0.1.tar.gz (122kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 122kB 773kB/s 
Installing collected packages: PyXerces
  Running setup.py install for PyXerces ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/bin/python2.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-FNousf/PyXerces/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-56rydK/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Xerces
    copying Xerces/etree.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Xerces
    copying Xerces/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Xerces
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Xerces/util
    copying Xerces/util/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Xerces/util
    copying Xerces/util/XMLUniDefs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Xerces/util
    running build_ext
    building 'Xerces.__Xerces' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/util
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/common
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/internal
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/framework
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/framework/psvi
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/parsers
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/dom
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/sax
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/validators
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/validators/common
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/validators/DTD
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/validators/schema
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/validators/schema/identity
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/validators/datatype
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/sax2
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-MW0004/python2.7-2.7.15=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/Xerces.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/Xerces.o -std=c++0x
    src/Xerces.cpp:13:10: fatal error: dom/DOMAttr.h: No such file or directory
     #include "dom/DOMAttr.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/usr/bin/python2.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-FNousf/PyXerces/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-56rydK/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-FNousf/PyXerces/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 0.0.1 released in 2014. Are you sure the package is usable? Anyway…

This is a bug in the package. The [distribution at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/PyXerces/#files) includes Python sources and C++ file but not include files. The headers are available in [the repository](https://github.com/mugwort-rc/pyXerces/tree/master/src/dom). Try to install directly from Github:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/mugwort-rc/pyXerces.git#egg=pyXerces
```

You need some additional dependencies. I stopped when the compilation started to require Boost libraries.